# Should there be a tag 'logic-pro-x'?

Tags: discussion, tags

The title has it all...

## My Reason

*My reason is slightly silly but if anyone agrees please edit with maybe a better reason however this is it:*

Well there is a 'garageband' tag so for people who need help with logic pro X why shouldn't there be a tag for that

Answer (score 3):

I would say no and that the existing [logic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) serves to identify questions that someone might want to follow and recognize expertise across the versions and editions of logic.

Is there a specific use case you are looking to assist with?